# select * returns CLOB

Tags: oracle, clob

I have not used oracle before  and I was to modify the clob data as it has my home phone number. But when I do `select * from` table shows `CLOB` and I cannot see the data. How can I see the data and how to I Update?

I need the query.

Comment: What are you using for the query?  SQL Developer?

Answer (score 3):

In `PL/SQL Developer`, select `ROWID` along with table columns:

```
SELECT  t.*, t.rowid
FROM    mytable t
```

This will allow you to edit the table's data.

Then just check a `...` button near the `CLOB` field and edit it.

You can load it from file or just type into the edit field.

Comment: And in PL/SQL Developer you could use: SELECT * FROM mytable FOR UPDATE

Answer (score 3):

What tool are you using to perform the query?  sqlplus will truncate select from a clob column to the value of the parameter long.  If you are using sqlplus then set long to a large enough value to hold the clob and then doing a simple select should return data.  Clobs are just text so it can be query as any other column in a table.    If you are using sqlplus and it returns nothing instead of partial, then make sure the column in the table is populated.

Comment: I use `set long 4096` to see the first 4096 characters of a clob.  Helpful for debugging problems with sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

In code?

Java (updating a CLOB field held as a field in an object called dbo):

```
String sql = "SELECT clobby_wobby FROM table WHERE uuid = ? FOR UPDATE";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setLong(1, dbo.getUID());
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    oracle.sql.CLOB clob = (oracle.sql.CLOB) ((OracleResultSet) rs).getClob(1);
    failed = writeClob(clob, dbo.getClobbyWobby());
}
rs.close();
ps.close();
```

where writeClob() is:

```
protected boolean writeClob(oracle.sql.CLOB clob, String data) throws SQLException {

    if (data == null) { return false; }
    return writeClob(clob, data.toCharArray());
}

protected boolean writeClob(oracle.sql.CLOB clob, char[] data) throws SQLException {

    if (data == null || clob == null) { return false; }
    char[] buffer = new char[clob.getBufferSize()];
    Writer os = clob.getCharacterOutputStream();
    int len = -1;
    CharArrayReader car = new CharArrayReader(data);
    try {
        while ((len = car.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
            os.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.error("IOException copying clob data into DB", ioe);
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            car.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {}
    }
    return true;
}
```

and sometimes I wonder why the darned Oracle driver itself can't detect that a field is a CLOB and just transparently cope with ps.setString("very long value"); itself... and this is where someone replies saying "why not use Oracle LOB Java utility methods?!" that I never knew about...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an old version of sqlplus?

If you are using sql developer, just make the column of the grid wider.

Answer (score 0):

I am using dbVisualizer and I did a regular update and it worked. Thanks MichaelN for informing that Clobs are just text so it can be query as any other column in a table. This helped me fix my issue in few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I present my approach for you situation: This is an example in pl/sql. You can create a procedure for read from clob.

```
  Declare 
  Variableclob Clob;
  Temp_Save Varchar2(32767);
  index_pass number;
  Begin

  For I In (select id_reporte from reporte where id_reporte between 201 and 218)
  Loop
  Index_Pass:=To_Number(I.Id_Reporte);
  Select Consulta Into Temp_Save From Reporte Where Id_Reporte=Index_Pass;
  Variableclob:=To_Clob(Temp_Save);

  Dbms_Output.Put_Line(Variableclob);

  End Loop ;
  End;

  Remember to use:
  set serveroutput on;
  begin DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(9999999999999); end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL developer, "Open" table. Select the "Data" tab (this will retrieve all data). Then in the Filter bar (top side), provide your criteria to get to the single row that you want to update. Update the required column(s) and then Commit the changes.